# How do I mount/unlock my custom (!) ecryptfs directory on login?

Tags: authentication, kernel, mount, passphrase, ecryptfs

I think I need to **add a key from the user keyring to the kernel keyring on login** for this, but let me just explain the whole thing:

I have a custom `ecryptfs` directory set up with a huge annoying passphrase, because [Ubuntu refuses to implement support for key files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/741364):

**2011**: *Unfortunately, we're not building ecryptfs against ssl at this time, due to license incompatibilities (as noted below). I'm going to leave this bug open, though, and try and get those sorted out.*

**2012**: *there are no plans to improve this feature in the near
term. It is a considerable amount of work, yet no developers have shown
interest in the feature.*

I want to mount/'unlock' this `ecryptfs` directory automatically when I log in, without having to enter this annoying passphrase manually. With an encrypted home in Ubuntu (also `ecryptfs`) this happens with a key that is unwrapped using the login password, but this does not work for custom mounts.

For other uses (e.g. `LUKS`) you can simply store the key/passphrase in your user keyring. But because `ecryptfs` works in the kernel, this key needs to be stored in the `kernel keyring`, not the `user keyring`.

Manually, you would add the key to the kernel keyring using `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` or `ecryptfs-manager`, after which you can mount and unmount the `ecryptfs` directory as much as you want. But after a reboot, this key is gone again, and with good reason.

But I want it back automatically after I login with my user so I can mount/unmount the `ecryptfs` directory again without having to enter it's password. How can I do this?

**update**

On **Archlinux** there is this tool called [ecryptfs-simple](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/ecryptfs-simple/) developed specifically for this purpose: *ecryptfs-simple is a utility for users that want to work with eCryptfs in the simplest way possible. The idea is to make eCryptfs as easy to use as EncFS.*

Apparently, you can setup automatic mounting with `ecryptfs-simple -a`, but this tool is not available for Ubuntu, and I don't know if this setup survives a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to manipulate keys, so keyctl might be your weapon of choice. Unless you're referring to some other Ubuntu-specific keyring I'm unfamiliar with. From man keyctl I can copy a key from the root/sudo/(kernel?) keyring into my user keyring with this command, something similar should work for you:

> sudo keyctl pipe (wantedkeyid#) | keyctl padd user newkeydesc @u

And maybe you've already read ArchWiki's excellent article on using eCryptfs. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_Encryption_with_eCryptfs#Auto-mounting
It's got info on using Ubuntu tools, or eCryptfs manually, and a section on auto-mounting (with PAM). Or maybe a simple bash script to `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` (reading your keyfile) & `mount` your folder would be easier? And ecryptfs itself supports reading the passphrase from a file too with `passphrase_passwd_file=`, see `man ecryptfs`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the passphrase somewhere, and then you can mount the filesystem automatically. But it's probably a bad idea — to save the key locally.

Comment: Exactly, I want to store it in *my* keyring which was invented exactly for securely remembering passwords, and which is protected by my encrypted home. The problem is, getting this key into the kernel keyring after the user keyring is unlocked.

Comment: Ok, now I understood the problem. You must save the value of environment variable that points to the keyring before logout, and after login restore it.